# Rightmost derivation word aaaccb

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I have got these context free grammar:

$S \implies aSA | a \\A \implies Ab|c$

The goal is find rightmost derivation of word $aaaccb$ a draw derivate tree, which corresponding with this derivation.

My result:

$S \implies aS\color{red}A \implies aS\color{red}Ab \implies a\color{red}Scb \implies aaS\color{red}Acb \implies aa\color{red}Sccb \implies aaaccb$

My derivation tree:

[image]

Please are derivation and tree correct?

And I would like to ask is there any way to get result with opposite procedure?

$\text{Like: }\hspace{10px}$$ aaaccb \implies ... \implies ... \implies S$

Comment: The derivation and tree look fine. I don’t see any way to accomplish the task in reverse.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Doing it in reverse would basically mean applying a LR parser, no?

Comment: LR do you mean  Left to Right ?

Comment: See [LR Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) on Wiki; L means it processes left to right, R means it creates a rightmost derivation.